# Spring Boot: Controller doesn't take in account Validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm trying to accomplish the use of a validator into the controller. The two fields `origin` and `destination` should be of three capital letters as IATA Code. But it acts without filter, and any request is accepted.

Set of validator interface:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = IATACodeValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IATACodeConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid IATA code";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Class of Validator:

```
public class IATACodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IATACodeConstraint, String> {

@Override
public void initialize(IATACodeConstraint iataCode) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String codeField, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return codeField != null && codeField.matches("^[A-Z]{3}+$")
            && (codeField.length() == 3);
}
```

Basic class:

```
public class CrazyAirRequest {

    @IATACodeConstraint
    private String origin;
    @IATACodeConstraint
    private String destination;
    private String departureDate;
    private String returnDate;
    private int passengerCount;

// getters & setters
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("flights")
@Validated
public class BusyFlightsController {


    CrazyAirDatabase crazyAirService;
    ToughJetDatabase toughJetService;

    @Autowired
    public BusyFlightsController(CrazyAirDatabase crazyAirService, ToughJetDatabase toughJetService) {
        this.crazyAirService = new CrazyAirDatabase();
        this.toughJetService = new ToughJetDatabase();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/crazy-air-response", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<CrazyAirResponse> getCrazyAirResponse(
            @RequestParam("origin")  String origin,
            @RequestParam("destination")  String destination,
            @RequestParam("departureDate") String departureDate,
            @RequestParam("returnDate") String returnDate,
            @RequestParam("passengerCount") int passengerCount
    ) {
        CrazyAirRequest crazyAirRequest = new CrazyAirRequest(origin, destination, departureDate, returnDate,
                passengerCount);
        return crazyAirService.getCrazyAirResponse(crazyAirRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@virendra chauhan: thank you for your inspiration.

I solved so:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/crazy-air-response", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<CrazyAirResponse> getCrazyAirResponse(
        @RequestParam("origin") @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]{3}", message = "Invalid IATA code")
                String origin,
        @RequestParam("destination") @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Z]{3}", message = "Invalid IATA code")
                String destination,
        @RequestParam("departureDate") String departureDate,
        @RequestParam("returnDate") String returnDate,
        @RequestParam("passengerCount") int passengerCount
) {
    CrazyAirRequest crazyAirRequest = new CrazyAirRequest(origin, destination, departureDate, returnDate,
            passengerCount);
    return crazyAirService.getCrazyAirResponse(crazyAirRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use @Pattern annotation without creating a custom validator for two fields as shown below :

```
@Pattern(regexp ="^[A-Z]{3}" message ="Invalid IATA code")
private String origin;
@Pattern(regexp ="^[A-Z]{3}" message ="Invalid IATA code")
private String destination;
```

Comment: I think they need a comma between the regex and the massage, but even with this, the controller doesn't filter. The unique way is to put             
@RequestParam("origin")  @Min(3) @Max(3) String origin
but we don't have the control on the letters and numbers, we cover only the length.